# Grouping Json data by years in order to create stacked bar using amchart

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, amcharts

I'm preparing data for dataProvider using amchart to create stacked Column chart like this https://www.amcharts.com/demos-v3/stacked-column-chart-v3/, 
i have the response of my service as its shown below, and i would like grouping data by year
so i have to change json data:

```
"Annee": "2018 / 2019",
"Chargeniv1": "Centre",
"MensuelCout": 123
},
{
"Annee": "2018 / 2019",
"Chargeniv1": "Main",
"MensuelCout": 456
},
{
"Annee": "2018 / 2019",
"Chargeniv1": "principaux",
"MensuelCout": 789
},
{
"Annee": "2017 / 2018",
"Chargeniv1": "structure",
"MensuelCout": 101
},
{
"Annee": "2017 / 2018",
"Chargeniv1": "principaux",
"MensuelCout": 629
},
{
"Annee": "2017 / 2018",
"Chargeniv1": "Main",
"MensuelCout": 985
}]
```

by this

```
[{
  "annee":"2018 / 2019"
  "Centre": 637612,
  "Main": 456,
  "principaux": 789,
    },
 {
  "annee":"2017 / 2018"
  "Centre": 101,
  "principaux": 629,
  "Main": 987,
}]
```

thank you for your attention

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `reduce` for grouping the objects by year and the function `Object.values` for extracting the grouped objects.

```js
let array = [ { "Annee": "2018 / 2019", "Chargeniv1": "Centre", "MensuelCout": 123 }, { "Annee": "2018 / 2019", "Chargeniv1": "Main", "MensuelCout": 456 }, { "Annee": "2018 / 2019", "Chargeniv1": "principaux", "MensuelCout": 789 }, { "Annee": "2017 / 2018", "Chargeniv1": "structure", "MensuelCout": 101 }, { "Annee": "2017 / 2018", "Chargeniv1": "principaux", "MensuelCout": 629 }, { "Annee": "2017 / 2018", "Chargeniv1": "Main", "MensuelCout": 985 }];
let result = Object.values(array.reduce((a, {Annee, Chargeniv1, MensuelCout}) => {
  a[Annee] = a[Annee] || (a[Annee] = {Annee});
  a[Annee][Chargeniv1] = (a[Annee][Chargeniv1] || 0) + MensuelCout;
  return a;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```

Comment: Just make sure you research and understand what `reduce` is doing, so you don't have to come back to StackOverflow each time you need to transform an array. 

Comment: @HaveSpacesuit I didn't get your comment.

Comment: i just want to say thank you , your answer is great and it works well thank you so much again,

Answer (score 1):

I will use filter functions and new set for unique years.

Your json response:

```
    let data = [
          {
            Annee: "2018 / 2019",
            Chargeniv1: "Centre",
            MensuelCout: 123
          }...
        ];
```

Get all years:

```
var years = new Set();
data.forEach((element, index) => {
  years.add(element.Annee);
});
```

Create a new array with the data and organize as you want.

```
var newData = [];
uniqueYears.forEach((year, index) => {
  newData.push({ year: year, cities: data.filter(y => y.Annee === year) });
});
```

Comment: I changed the code I create the years variable as new Set by default and add the elements into the loop.